# What does "down" mean in this sense

Tags: meaning

A commercial from "Planet Fitness" and if you've seen the commercials they say "5 dollars down and then 10 dollars per month (repeats)"
It'd be really helpful because I couldn't find an answer 
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

In marketing contexts such as this, the word *down* is a commonly used shorthand for "down payment."

> An initial amount paid at the time of purchase, in installment buying, time sales, etc.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/down-payment

In other words, the Planet Fitness contract expects the customer to make a one-time payment of $5 and then $10 each month.